# How common was training with swords and other weapons at Newton's time in England?

Tags: weapons, crime

I read in Levenson's book *Newton and the Counterfeiter* that when Newton was traveling to London from Cambridge, he stopped at an inn along the way to wait for other travelers so that they all could travel together because of highwaymen.  I wonder if a scholar like Newton would have had at least some rudimentary knowledge of swordsmanship.
If he didn't, was there a time that almost every child would have had some sort of self-defense training involving if not swords, quarter staffs or something?
(And if this was a common teaching, when did it stop being common?)

I visualize that the past as being much more violent than today and I think murder statistics bear this out.

Comment: Some details on a book on self-defense written by a student of Newton's here:  https://fencingclassics.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/matters-of-gravity-sir-isaac-newton%E2%80%99s-combative-student/

Comment: An *hereditary gentleman* of Newton's age would certainly have been taught basics of fencing and wrestling, but likely not a quarter staff as that would have been thought rather a *low-born* weapon. However, Newton's *gentile* status was earned rather than inherited, so perhaps knew his way around a quarter staff but probably had no training in fencing or wrestling.

Comment: Even if Newton had been an expert swordsman, he would (if sensible) have been reluctant to take on a gang of highwaymen by himself.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens I see comments but what I should be seeing is answers.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Possibly because no one has enough specific information to answer the question?  (I might remark that being a scholar does not preclude a knowledge of swordsmanship: I practiced both European fencing and kendo while I was in school.)

Comment: @jamesqf I've learned a variety of martial arts, but am expert in none of them.  What I am lethally competent in is the use of pistols, rifles, and grenade launchers.  Sabre and epee?  Not so much.    This SE is still in beta.  I am not sure how we get the signal to noise ratio to a state where it gets out of beta, but people answering in comments and the extended arguments in comments cannot be helping us.  I thus occasionally post reminders that answers belong in answers, not in comments.  I'd like to see this SE graduate.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: I disagree.  The comments & discussion in them are by far the best part.  Especially for a question like this, where a) there may be no answer, because not enough is known about Newton's life; and b) if there is an answer, it could probably be found more effectively by reading a few Newton biographies.

Comment: @jamesqf If we all feel that way, we'll never get out of beta.

Comment: Related: https://history.stackexchange.com/q/32823/2848 . There was probably compulsory militia service for Protestant males aged 16-60, meaning that there was probably some theoretical requirement for Newton to have drilled and practiced with some kind of weapon, maybe a firearm or longbow, and he was probably supposed to have maintained such a weapon in his house. In reality, I doubt that such a requirement would have been enforced on a man of Newton's social class (theoretically a cleric, as a Cambridge don?), unless there was some major scare about invasion, Catholic revolt, ...

Comment: @KorvinStarmast: Is that a problem?  If getting out of beta means this site becomes less interesting & informative, like some sites which delete every interesting discussion, then I vote to stay in beta forever :-)

Comment: `I wonder if a scholar like Newton would have had at least some rudimentary knowledge of swordsmanship.` - As I see from comments and answer, Newton's ability in using a sword cannot be confirmed, but for scholars *in general* that can be related to them having military training: Descartes, for one, was a military man between 1618 and 1620 in the Protestant Dutch States Army under the command of Maurice of Nassau.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that Newton had some basic military training during his education at The King's School, Grantham. The English Civil War had only recently ended and there would have been plenty of men with military experience around. I doubt anyone was giving teenage boys swords though.

Newton was a gentleman by birth but the distinction between gentleman and yeoman farmer was rather nebulous and more down to social identification than precise demarcations of wealth or property. The substantial house at Colsterworth, the fact his mother Hannah could read and write, and her subsequent marriage to a clergyman, are good indicators that Newton would have been considered a 'gentleman farmer'. However this absolutely did not imply the sort of education received by the nobility on a country estate (which would have included riding, swordsmanship etc.). Newton was a long way below this socially.

Ben Crowell is correct that his adult status as a don (effectively regarded as a cleric, although Newton famously never took Holy Orders) would have excused him from any sort of military service later in life.