# Youngest age for the militia in the middle ages

Tags: military, middle-ages, children

I know it probably differed from village to village, town to town, city to city, but what was the standard bare minimum age for anyone to join the local militia or receive any sort of combat/survival training back in the middle ages? You know, besides something high class like squire training. I'm talking among the commoners.

Comment: related: https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/32823/what-was-the-historical-context-of-the-2nd-amendment-to-the-us-constitution